# Use where in lookup(aggregate) mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to check if user have `{meta:"city" ,value:"london"}` in metas array, then return it.

I tried this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "usersmeta",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "user",
      as: "metas"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      phoneverified: true
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to search inside array field.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "usersmeta",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "user",
      as: "metas"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      phoneverified: true,
      metas: {
        $elemMatch: {
          meta: "city",
          value: "london"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dhC2wB0x47M)